# grovysh imports when working with HBase fail

Tags: groovy, hbase, groovysh

What *.jar I need to make my groovysh work with hbase 1.1.2 i am trying to run a simple script and the following imports fail - 
groovy:000>

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
```

> ERROR java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/HeapSize
>           at java_lang_Runnable$run.call (Unknown Source)
>   groovy:000>

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result
```

> ERROR java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/CellScannable
>           at java_lang_Runnable$run.call (Unknown Source)
>    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
>   Invalid import definition: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes'; reason: startup failed:
>   script14891462389401754287428.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
>    @ line 1, column 1.

```
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
```

I have loaded hbase-client.jar in my -classthpath.  Just need to write a simple script that puts and increments hbase variables and execute via groovysh.

Edit 1
I get this now
groovy:000> groovy.grape.Grape.grab(group:'org.apache.hbase', module:'hbase-client', version:'1.3.0')
ERROR java.lang.RuntimeException:
Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: junit#junit;4.12!junit.jar, download failed: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7!slf4j-api.jar, download failed: org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.6.1!slf4j-log4j12.jar]
groovy:000> groovy.grape.Grape.grab('org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.3.0')

Comment: See my new error

Answer (score 0):

hbase client has a lot of dependencies:

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client/1.1.1/

You can't just grab one jar and stick it on the classpath, you need a whole load of them

I don't use groovysh, but you should be able to do:

```
:grab 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.3.0'
```

And that should pull down `hbase-client` and all of its dependencies on to your classpath

Comment: sorry I totally new to groovy I just want a fat jar in my classpath so I can run a simple groovysh script that runs a simple put to HBase.   something like hbase.jar.  I tried to include all jars in my `hbase classpath` but it failed

Comment: Try removing all the jars you added, then from inside groovysh do:  `:grab 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.3.0'`

Comment: That should pull down all the dependencies (updated answer with this info)